# Russian Book Recommendations - Self Study

Tags: self-learning, reference-request, grammar, russian

I’m looking for books to learn Russian, specifically the overall grammar “rules”: conjugations, declensions, etc. Level: Beginner up to advanced. The books should be for self study. For reference, I currently have no knowledge of Russian, my first language is Spanish and I also speak English and German.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. So you are looking for self-study books that focus on grammar only? And the source language should preferably be Spanish, with English and German as alternatives?

Comment: @Tsundoku Hi, thank you for your answer. I’m looking for a good self-study book, or series of books, to learn Russian. It doesn’t have to be exclusively grammar but I do want it to focus mainly on it. Source language should preferably be English and the other two as alternatives.